# Need troubleshooting advice for H.264 stream (works in PC VLC, but not on CumulusTV App)

Tags: encoding, h.264, android-tv, bitstream

I have an HDMI source connected to a Chinese HD HDMI Encoder box. Playback to VLC on my PC works (open network stream http://192.168.0.150:80/hdmi)
Stream is NOT leaving my local network (on purpose)
I cannot get a signal to display on my Google Nexus Player or my NVidia Shield via Cumulus TV app. (The point being to integrate the feed into the Google Live Channels app) I have tried adjusting several of the settings to no avail. Should I be trying a specific format? I tried the Fiddler (didn't see anything descriptive in that tool) but still have no definitive answers. I am pretty sure this device only produces a H.264 bitstream, which works in the PC version of VLC, but I have no luck on my androidTV devices (to include VLC). I can also get playback on my android PHONE in VLC...

seeking help/ troubleshooting advice...

main stream settings are:

- H.264 Level： high profile  Encoding frame rate： 30[5-30]
- Bitrate control：vbr   Key interval： 30[5-200]
- Encoded size： auto MinQp： 3[1-51] MaxQp： 32[MinQp-51]
- MaxBitrate： 8000[16-12000]
- Audio bitrate：192000  Audio channel：L+R
- Audio Codec：AAC Resample：Disable  Package：B  HTTP： Enable  /hdmi (begin with "/")
- HTTP Port：80[1-65535] Change TS ID：Disable
- transport_stream_id： 300[256-3800]pmt_start_pid： 480[256-3800]
- stream_start_pid： 481[256-3800]RTSP： Disable Multicast IP： Disable
- RTMP server ip： Disable ONVIF：Disable Enable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your encoder can stream three different formats:

- Http - probably HLS
- RTMP
- RTP/RTSP

Now the question is which formats do your clients support and is the format on the above list.
You could install Fiddler on your PC (web app debugger) to verify that your streaming box actually serves HLS.
Since you know that VLC plays your stream you could try to install VLC on your Google Nexus player: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc